# Snowflake automatically rounding number during COPY INTO transformation

Tags: sql, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am using an AWS S3 stage to load .csv data into my Snowflake database.

The .csv columns are as follows:

[image]

My COPY INTO command is this:

```
copy into MY_TABLE(tot_completions, tot_hov, parent_id) 
from (select t.$1, to_decimal(REPLACE(t.$2, ',')), 1 from @my_stage t) 
pattern='.*file_path.*' file_format = my_file_format ON_ERROR=CONTINUE;
```

The Tot. HOV column is being automatically rounded to 40 and 1 respectively. The data type is decimal, and I tried it as a float as well, even though they should both be able to store decimals.

My desired result is to store the decimal as is displayed on the .csv without rounding. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In addition the answers below, you might also want to consider doing this transformation AFTER your COPY INTO statement, if you can.  It's actually faster to load data directly and then do the transformations as a 2nd step than it is to do it in the COPY command...typically.  For a small, 2 column file, might not make a difference.  A larger file with a ton of transformations, it will.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. How would you recommend going about that? a. Creating a temp table for the transformations to take place or b. transforming directly in the main table?

Comment: Yes - a transient stage table so you don't have to create it every time.  And then you either truncate before you load or use a stream over the table (if you want to keep a persistent copy of your raw data in the stage table).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the precision and scale:

```
create or replace table number_conv(expr varchar);
insert into number_conv values ('12.3456'), ('98.76546');

select expr, to_number(expr),  to_number(expr, 10, 1), to_number(expr, 10, 8) from number_conv;

+----------+-----------------+------------------------+------------------------+
| EXPR     | TO_NUMBER(EXPR) | TO_NUMBER(EXPR, 10, 1) | TO_NUMBER(EXPR, 10, 8) |
|----------+-----------------+------------------------+------------------------|
| 12.3456  |              12 |                   12.3 |            12.34560000 |
| 98.76546 |              99 |                   98.8 |            98.76546000 |
+----------+-----------------+------------------------+------------------------+
```

and:

```
select column1,
       to_decimal(column1, '99.9') as d0,
       to_decimal(column1, '99.9', 9, 5) as d5,
       to_decimal(column1, 'TM9', 9, 5) as td5
from values ('1.0'), ('-12.3'), ('0.0'), ('  - 0.1   ');

+---------+-----+-----------+-----------+
| COLUMN1 |  D0 |        D5 |       TD5 |
|---------+-----+-----------+-----------|
| 1.0     |   1 |   1.00000 |   1.00000 |
| -12.3   | -12 | -12.30000 | -12.30000 |
| 0.0     |   0 |   0.00000 |   0.00000 |
| - 0.1   |   0 |  -0.10000 |  -0.10000 |
+---------+-----+-----------+-----------+
```

See more [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_decimal.html)